# winsock2.h, no such file or directory

Tags: visual-c++

I have this error while compiling my Visual C++ project in Visual Studio 2008 on XP. How to resolve this error :(

```
Error   1   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h    68  WOT
```

Comment: Is there any additional SDK that I need to install beside my VS2008?

Comment: Casual solution: `#ifdef _WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32")
#endif` including windows first avoids future problems but possible only if you have defined `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Windows SDK is not configure correctly. The easiest way to fix this is to install [Windows 7 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx). (yes, you can install it on windows xp and develop for xp)

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ff851942.aspx for list of Windows SDK for varying operating systems and frameworks.

Comment: installtion of windows 7 SDK is failing for me. I guess it becuase I have VS 2013 installed on my machine. is there any other workaround ?

Answer (score -4):

simply go to project->project properties
linker->input
 in additional dependencies add ws2_32.lib
linker ->command line add here ws2_32.lib 
click start

Comment: Why would you think this is a linking problem?

Comment: Are you thinking of `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32")`?