# Error in installing node.js module using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install the following module using node.js, but keep on getting the following error. Do you have any suggestions on what I should do? So I am using windows 7 and have installed .NET Framework 2.0 SDK as well.

```
npm install execSync

MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". 
To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 
2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or
3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to install a trial version of visual studio and run npm in the visual studio command prompt as administrator. Visual studio 2012 does the job.

Comment: I have encountered this error a couple of times and never (re)installed any components to fix it.Unfortunately I cannot recall how to solve it any more; i am currently facing the issue again.
Nevertheless I checked it and python, Visual C++ and all the other stuff mentioned in this or other answers were installed on my PC anyways.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add `VCBuild.exe` to your path. Check out this answer on how to do it: [Testacular install fails, no vcbuild.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833736/testacular-install-failes-no-vcbuild-exe)

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now I am getting the following error d:\users\hduser\.node-gyp\0.10.12\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory [D:\Users\hduser\node_modules\ffi\node_modules\ref\build\binding.sln]

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623129/winsock2-h-no-such-file-or-directory?

Comment: thanks @verybadalloc this answer worked, its really messy the way node.js is on windows.

Comment: I don't have the file path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages, perhaps because I'm using 8.0? I created the file path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

ran in an administration window and we will see:

```
Starting installation...
Launched installers, now waiting for them to finish.
This will likely take some time - please be patient!
Waiting for installers... -Successfully installed Python 2.7
Waiting for installers... /Successfully installed Visual Studio Build Tools.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

will resolve 90% of the install issues in windows for node

Answer (score 1):

This steps helped me a lot:

"According to the readme file in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1, to ensure that your system has a supported configuration, uninstall the following products and then reinstall them in the order listed:"

1 - Visual C++ 2010 Express or Visual Studio 2010

2 - Windows SDK 7.1 **Note: If you get error on installation, maybe this link will help you.**

3 - Visual Studio 2010 SP1

4 - Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1

For me, only the step two was enough.
Pay attention in second step's note "Note: If you get error on installation, maybe this link will help you". I had problem and this tip was important.

For more information, this link can be useful: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Setup

Comment: This answer pointed me in right direction! Thanx! http://stackoverflow.com/a/15937635/2873481

Answer (score 0):

After trying various .Net and Visual I finally managed to get npm to load and build mongoose on Windows 8.1 by downloading Visual Studio 2013 Prof

ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winsock/winsock2/qos.h

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, even after installing Visual Studio 2015 and adding the path to VCBuild.exe to Environment Variables -> PATH, this error was occuring when i tried to `npm install`. Restarting the machine didn't resolve the error. I tried starting the app using `node app.js` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

This command will add necessary packages.

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`