# kafka-node module exception

Tags: node.js, exception, npm, apache-kafka

I am trying to publish message to kafka broker from nodejs. when am trying to install kafka-node module in nodejs window. am getting exception related to python.

```
 C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install kafka-node
-
> snappy@4.1.2 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\kafka-node\node_modules\snappy
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\kafka-node\node_modules\snappy>if not defined npm_config_node_g
yp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin
\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.0, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
gyp\lib\configure.js:121:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.j
s:110:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm
\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\kafka-node\node_modules\snappy
gyp ERR! node -v v4.3.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\b
in\\npm-cli.js" "install" "kafka-node"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! snappy@4.1.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the snappy@4.1.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the snappy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls snappy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

Is there any relation between kafka-node with python.  I had setup python 3.4 and again tried to install kafka-node module, it says gyp is not suppported in python3.4 version . ( Below is error message )

So I installed python 2.6 and and again tried to install kafka-node again it is giving below error

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\kafka-node\node_modules\snappy>if not defined npm_config_node_g
yp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin
\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m"
switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) ins
tall the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of
the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modul
es\kafka-node\node_modules\snappy\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit c
ode: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nod
e-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm
\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\kafka-node\node_modules\snappy
gyp ERR! node -v v4.3.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\b
in\\npm-cli.js" "install" "kafka-node"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! snappy@4.1.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the snappy@4.1.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the snappy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls snappy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

Any help appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you revived on your second attempt is:

> MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) ins
>   tall the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of
>   the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.

Do you have Visual Studio with a C++ compiler installed? if not you should install it.

Other helpful answers can be found on this post :
[Error in installing node.js module using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496189/error-in-installing-node-js-module-using-npm)

Comment: I did not really understand this dependency, what is the dependency between node kafka and .NET and Visual studio .. thanks

Comment: To install kafka-node module you need to have VCBuild.exe. The easy way to get that is to follow the steps mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

node-gyp is used to build the snappy dependency. A compression library. If you don't use compression in your kafka messages you can safely ignore this. This dependency was made optional in version 0.3.3.

If you don't use snappy you can just install the module with `--no-optional` flag:

`npm install kafka-node --no-optional`