# Running NodeJs serialPort on windows

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, serial-port

I am trying to install NodeJs serialPort on windows, but each time i do `npm install serialport` i run into the following error

```
    MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". 

    **To fix this**

    1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK 

    2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 

    3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  

[C:\[...]\electron-with-express\express-app\node_modules\serialport\build\binding.sln]
```

I tried installing `.net Framework 2.0` but the issue persist.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Visual Studio, or some other Microsoft package that includes a C++ compiler?

have a read of this post:
[Error in installing node.js module using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496189/error-in-installing-node-js-module-using-npm)

Comment: I have visual studio 2015 installed

Comment: @John Add when you installed it did you include the Visual C++ environment? If so you should be able to see something in your path that points to the VC++ compiler.