# Qt C++ include winsock2.h

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, winsock2

I am currently trying to get WebSocket++ to work in my Qt project. The problem is that WebSocket++ can not find "winsock2.h".

I added these lines to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86"
win32:LIBS += -lWS2_32
```

I tried different variations of the lib name, which I found in some previous questions here on stackoverflow, without any success. What am I doing wrong? All help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the appropriate Windows SDK (8.1 as it implies in path).

[winsock2.h, no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623129/winsock2-h-no-such-file-or-directory)